# Create weekly counts from a specified date over multiple years

Tags: r

I have mock data that looks similar to this.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2022-11-07", "2022-11-09", "2022-11-10", "2022-11-14", "2022-11-15", "2022-11-17", "2022-11-21", "2022-11-22", "2022-11-23"), 
  Concentration = c(10, 12, 15, 16, 16, 14, 11, 9, 6)
)

df

        Date Concentration
1 2022-11-07            10
2 2022-11-09            12
3 2022-11-10            15
4 2022-11-14            16
5 2022-11-15            16
6 2022-11-17            14
7 2022-11-21            11
8 2022-11-22             9
9 2022-11-23             6
```

What I need to do is attach a weekly count starting from a pre-specified date.

```
data_start_date <- as.Date("2022-09-25")
```

Ultimately, the code I need would take the difference between df$Date and data_start_date and convert that to a weekly count- preference would be to have this count start a new week on Sundays. This data also extends over 2 years, so I would need a way for it to continuously count up, not to reset back to 1 at 52/53 weeks. Output would look something like this (assuming the week of 9/25/2022 is week 1 and not week 0).

```
Date Concentration          Weekly_Count
1 2022-11-07            10        7
2 2022-11-09            12        7
3 2022-11-10            15        7
4 2022-11-14            16        8
5 2022-11-15            16        8
6 2022-11-17            14        8
7 2022-11-21            11        9
8 2022-11-22             9        9
9 2022-11-23             6        9
```

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting your first `Date` column to a number-like Date-class object, we can simply subtract from your reference date, convert to weeks, and then take the ceiling of it to get the numbers you're expecting.

```r
df |>
  transform(Date = as.Date(Date)) |>
  transform(Weekly_Count = ceiling(as.numeric(Date - as.Date("2022-09-25"), units = "weeks")))
#         Date Concentration Weekly_Count
# 1 2022-11-07            10            7
# 2 2022-11-09            12            7
# 3 2022-11-10            15            7
# 4 2022-11-14            16            8
# 5 2022-11-15            16            8
# 6 2022-11-17            14            8
# 7 2022-11-21            11            9
# 8 2022-11-22             9            9
# 9 2022-11-23             6            9
```